# Can't insert sha256 hash into SQLite3 table - NodeJs

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

I'm creating a table of sha256 hashes using SQLite3 and NodeJs
When attempting to insert a integer and random hash, I get the following error.

```js
{ Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855 errno: 1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR' }
```

This is the source for creating and inserting data into the table

```js
// * Create ~ Open Hashes Database
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./hashes.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE, (e => {
  if (e) {
    console.log('Failed to open/create hashes database')
  }

  console.log('Successfully opened / created')
}));

const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').digest('hex');

// * 1 Create Database
db.run("CREATE TABLE hashes(seq INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, hash VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)", (e) => {
  if (e) return console.log(e);
  console.log('Created database')
});

db.run(`INSERT INTO hashes VALUES (1, ${hash})`, (e) => {
  if (e) return console.log(e);
  console.log("successfully inserted", 1, hash);
})
```

Column 1 (Seq) is simply a sequential incremented integer (1,2,3....)
and the second column is the hash of type VARCHAR.

Comment: This error occur when table already created?

Comment: Yes it occurred after the table was created

Comment: Did you execute only data insertion part without table creation part after table has been created?

Comment: Yep. If I run only the insertion code, it throws that error. Just for clarification, the hash in the error is just the hash that was just generated during that run - Since i'm using crypto.createHash()

Comment: try `INSERT INTO hashes VALUES (1, "${hash}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think issue is you are using hash directly in query without defining it as a string/varchar hence sqlite thinks it is a column.

```
db.run(`INSERT INTO hashes VALUES (1, "${hash}")`, (e) => {
  if (e) return console.log(e);
  console.log("successfully inserted", 1, hash);
})
```

Comment: You should really use single quotes for string literals. While sqlite will accept that it may not work if there's a column with that name - unlikely for hashes, but still. https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#double_quoted_string_literals_are_accepted

Answer (score 2):

**Please god use params not string interpolation to pass dynamic values into queries. This is true of *any* programming language interfacing with *any* SQL engine. String interpolation opens you up to massive sql injection vulnerabilities, see https://bobby-tables.com/**

This is clearly documented and recommended in the node sqlite3 API:

https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback

```
      db.run("UPDATE tbl SET name = ? WHERE id = ?", "bar", 2);
```

This acts as if the values `"bar"` and `2` were put in place of the two `?`, respectively.

---

In your case, this should do:

```
db.run("INSERT INTO hashes VALUES (1, ?)", hash, (e) => {
  if (e) return console.log(e);
  console.log("successfully inserted", 1, hash);
})
```

It looks better, is easier, and is safer.

Note that I changed the backtick interpolation `-string to a doublequote "-string. This is intentional. Don't interpolate values into SQL strings.